# Can we use objects of one structure as members of another structure or union?

Tags: c, structure, unions

Can we use objects of one structure as members of another structure or union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. Structs are types, and fields of structs can have any valid type:

```
struct Point
{
  int x, y;
};

struct Rectangle
{
 struct Point top_left;
 struct Point bottom_right;
};
```

This is very basic, and where C gets a lot of its expressive powers from.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course:

```
struct address {
    char street[100];
    int number;
};

struct people {
    char name[100];
    struct address addr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Short question - short answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the shortest answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Example:

```
typedef struct MyStruct1
{
  int a;
  float b;
}MyStruct;

typedef struct AnotherStruct
{
  int number;
  MyStruct m_field2;
}AnotherStruct;

int main()
{
  AnotherStruct obj1;
  obj1.number = 10;
  obj1.m_field2.a = 10;
  obj1.m_field2.b = 34.43;
  return 0;
}
```